# Add invisible tab Item to App

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab App with 4 tabs. The tab view controllers all link to the Tab Bar Controller.

However, I don't necessarily need a 5th tab, but I need a hidden view that the app is first time loaded(note:By not clicking any button..).

How should I go about doing this?

Usually, I create a view controller and create a relationship to the tab bar controller and set the view controller class.

However, I do not want to see a fifth tab for the hidden view.

Note that the fifth view should still be showing the tab bar when it is loaded and visible.